# Puppeteer and Playwright chrome headful bugs when making a screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, playwright

I am currently developing a node.js script that needs to launch a headful chromium instance using Puppeteer and then make a screenshot of a page every 3 seconds, this is my code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function init (){
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://example.com');
 screenshot(page)
};

async function screenshot(page){

 let buffer = await page.screenshot();
 let imageBuffer = buffer.toString('base64');
 // save imageBuffer to database
 setTimeout(screenshot, 3000, page)
}
```

My current issue is that I need the user to still be able to normally navigate on the browser and on his computer but this impossible as :

1. The page lags when making the screenshot as you can see on the following video : https://youtu.be/Tl2w-qKckkc
2. The browser window focuses and goes on top of all the windows when making the screenshot.

I also tried using Playwright but the same bug occurs when using it with chromium. Can someone please help.

Comment: Exactly what prevents: "the user to still be able to normally navigate on the browser and on his computer" ? Do you mean the flickering (zoom out) while puppeteer creates the screenshot would cause issues? It was like this since the first release, it doesn't affect anything, just a visual glitch.

Comment: When you need to make a screenshot every 3 seconds it does have an effect. Moreover the fact that it brings the window to focus.

Comment: These phenomena are related to Chromium itself and not Puppeteer nor Playwright. If you are suffering from performance issues during screenshot creation that is a known and documented issue https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=741689, especially that is the case with OS X, but I've heard performance related complains about headful and headless running as well. ...

Comment: ... You can try to launch Puppeteer with `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage']` args, it may provides better performance. About the focus on window: it is just a visual thing, it does not affect how Puppeteer interacts with the pages. If it bothers you feel free to raise a ticket for the Chromium team: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.

Comment: Ok thanks will report it asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Playwright, do the following:

```js
// Affects all the platforms.
const page = await browser.newPage({ viewport: null });
```

```js
// Local fix for those using Apple hardware with Retina displays.
const page = await browser.newPage({ deviceScaleFactor: 2 });
```

I posted a detailed reply at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2576. Please feel free to follow up and ask questions / request features there!

Comment: Thanks ! However I still got a question, how to prevent the window from focusing when the screenshot is made ?

Comment: That's because we bring the window to front for no good reason.  Let me follow up in the bug and fix this!